Proof Clarification: $f$ is convex iff it's convex when restricted to every line intersecting its domain
About this answer: Proof: A function is convex iff it is convex when restricted to any line ..
I need clarification about the proof the user @gerw gave. I managed to understand and perform the proof of the $(\implies)$, and I was looking at the other side.
Then by contradiction, we assume $f$ is not convex. Then either the domain of $g$ is not convex or else (...). I'm interested in this first point.
I don't understand the part where he says:

If $\operatorname{dom}(f)$ is not convex, there exist $x,y \in \operatorname{dom}(f)$ and $\lambda \in (0,1)$ with $\lambda \, x + (1-\lambda) \, y \not\in \operatorname{dom}(f)$. Now, set $v = y - x$ and use the $g$ as in the statement of the theorem. Then, it is easy to check that $\operatorname{dom}(g)$ is not convex, since it contains $0$ and $1$, but not $1-\lambda$.

I tried to write $g(t) = f(x+tv) = f(x + t(y-x)) = f(x(1-t) + ty)$ but from here, if $f$ is not convex then I would assume it's concave (?) hence $f(x(1-t) + ty)) > (1-t)f(x) + tf(y)$ but I don't understand how to relate this with $g$, and most of all how he concludes that points $1$ and $0$ belong to the domain of $f$, but $1-\lambda$ does not.
Thank you!

'Most' functions are neither convex nor concave.

@geetha290krm Ok, but the point of my question was that I don't understand the proof for the first case. I mean he says that $f$ is not convex if either its domain is not convex or if the definition of convexity doesn't hold. Here the proof to show the domain of $f$ is acutally convex is weird to me. How can you prove a general domain is not convex? It's not always $\mathbb{R}^n$ I mean. It's a strange tour the one he made, passing even through the domain of $g$...
